Tomcat Fails to Connect to Elasticsearch with UnknownHostException
I'm trying to run Usergrid following the instructions on the website. I managed to get the requirements up and running (as far as I know), but running Usergrid/Tomcat throws:
root@usergrid:~# systemctl start tomcat
08:01:01,536  WARN netty:620 - [default] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x76523f9a]], closing connection
java.net.UnknownHostException: 192.168.2.237:9200
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:613)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(OioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:109)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(OioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:69)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:634)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:207)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:229)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:182)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannelsLight(NettyTransport.java:769)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:737)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNodeLight(NettyTransport.java:709)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLight(TransportService.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$3.run(UnicastZenPing.java:376)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
^C
root@usergrid:~# curl -v http://192.168.2.237:9200
*   Trying 192.168.2.237:9200...
* Connected to 192.168.2.237 (192.168.2.237) port 9200 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.2.237:9200
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 334
< 
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Pisces",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.0",
    "build_hash" : "bc94bd81298f81c656893ab1ddddd30a99356066",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-11-05T14:26:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.2.237 left intact
root@usergrid:~# 


Elasticsearch is listening on two ports - 9200 for REST requests and 9300 for transport protocol requests. Based on the stacktrace and it looks like Usergrid is using transport client. Moreover, based on the error message the system doesn't seem to extract port in the ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOSTS environment variable leading to it treating this port as part of the hostname. Fortunately port 9300 is the default, so we can simply omit the port:
ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOSTS="192.168.2.237"

On a separate note make sure that your elasticsearch instance is not exposed to outside world. All versions that usergrid supports are obsolete and has very serious security issues. Ideally I would try migrating to something modern ASAP.

Similar error when switching ports, I will try to run elasticsearch on the same host to check

How do you specify the elasticsearch address in configuration? And what exact error do you get?

java.net.UnknownHostException: 192.168.2.237:9300
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:613)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(OioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:109)


Set via the setenv of Tomcat:
#!/bin/bash

export USERGRID_CLUSTER_NAME="usergrid"
export CASSANDRA_HOSTS="192.168.2.239:9160"
export CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME="usergrid"
export ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NAME="usergrid-elasticsearch"
export ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOSTS="192.168.2.237:9300"


I actually remember now why I am installing Elasticsearch on a different machine, it was because of the error 'Jun 19 15:28:36 elasticsearch elasticsearch[345]: sysctl: permission denied on key "vm.max_map_count"' since my Usergrid is running in a Linux Container (CT)

I would try ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOSTS="192.168.2.237" if that doesn't work it must be connectivity problems to port 9300 on that machine from whatever container you run tomcat in.

Oh, it should be ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS no _ between elastic and search

Hi, thanks, this worked: ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOSTS="192.168.2.237" (without the port) I guess the problem was the port was taken as part of the hostname or something

Yeah, the error message looked like it wasn't parsing out the port. It kind of contradicts the docs though. Glad it worked for you!

Hi, you can update your answer based on the solution in your comment so I can accept is as the answer for you.
